# How do I get the last inserted id in a generic way with Poco?

Tags: sql, sqlite, poco-libraries

I have scoured the documentation for Poco but could not find a way to retrieve the last inserted id for an INSERT INTO Table operation.

The [Statement::execute](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Data.Statement.html#7389) documentation says that it returns the number of records affected (which could be greater than one for a bulk insert).

If it makes any difference I'm currently using SQLite but would like a generic solution that works across different database engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQLite, execute a statement, SELECT last_insert_rowid()

I know that isn't a generic answer.

But, this is how they do it in [Ti.Database](https://github.com/marshall/titanium/blob/master/modules/ti.Database/database_binding.cpp) module - which is a module for Titanium that uses poco. They select last_insert_rowid() and then set that as a property of the statement.

Comment: That's what I am currently using but the problem is if there's another operation on the database concurrent with the one that is being processed: [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html). I was wondering if there was something like what Qt [has](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html#lastInsertId)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such facility in Poco. Rather than bending backwards to abstract something that is inconsistent across different back-ends, we chose not to provide it at all and leave users to deal directly with the back-end. See [this discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/poco/feature-requests/60/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the discussion. Unfortunately I am getting a 403, Read access required. I wonder if there are any recommended solutions, such as using last_insert_rowid() and making sure that there are no intervening queries that could change the id?

Comment: Not sure if signing up to SF would help - we have disabled that project a while ago but it still lets me see the forums. `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` was recommended in the discussion. As for "intervening queries", that depends on your application logic - as long as you have control what is executed, you should get the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for fetching that for me, this is the same that @RobertDupuy suggested in the other answer so that is good confirmation of the best solution so far. I am signed on to SF but it doesn't matter anyway...

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
template <typename IDType>
IDType ActiveRecord<IDType>::lastInsertID(Poco::Data::Session& session)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**